# Extracting vectors from a tuple

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

I have got `int`s, a `vector<int>`, and a `vector<string>` in a tuple function. If there is an error when running this function, it will return a tuple of: `{0, 0, {0}, {"0"}}`. The `int`s have no errors. I have simplified this code a lot, and can't figure out why I can't use a vector in a tuple. It puts a red squiggly line under the `{`.
Here is a much simpler version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


tuple<vector<int>, vector<string>> tuples()
{
    return { {0}, {"0"} };
}


int main()
{
    tuple<vector<int>, vector<string>> result = tuples();
    if (get<0>(result) == {0} && get<1>(result) == {"0"})
    {
        cout << "It worked!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you can't use vectors in tuples, what is the other way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `initialiser` lists `{0}` on the right hand side i.e after the `==`.

`You can't use vectors in tuples` is a `false` statement.

Changing your code to:

```
tuple<vector<int>, vector<string>> result = tuples();
vector<int> v = {0};
vector<string> v2 = {"0"};
if (get<0>(result) == v && get<1>(result) == v2)
{
    cout << "It worked!\n";
}
```

Gives the desired results.

It is also worth investigating why the compiler put a `squiggly` red line under your code by looking at the output from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one :) As far as you simply can't return initializer lists(implicit constructor of vector), you can return created tuple with vector constructors(explicit).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<string>> tuples()
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::vector<int>({0}), std::vector<std::string>({"0"}));
}


int main()
{
    tuple<vector<int>, vector<string>> result = tuples();
    if (get<0>(result) == std::vector<int>{0} && get<1>(result) == std::vector<std::string>{"0"})
    {
        cout << "It worked!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```